# Add an object to an array with mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a nodejs webserver that allows file uploads and I would like to add the files uploaded to users, but every time I try to add to the users db array, It says it adds it, but when I read the users files, it returns an empty array. I used the following code to try to add to the array:

```
for (var x in files){
 User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id,
  {$push: {"files":{name:files[x].filename}}},
  function (err, doc) {
   if (err) throw err;
   console.log(doc);
 });
}
```

The schema used is this:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {type:String, required: true, trim: true, lowercase:true, unique: true},
 hash: {type:String, required: true },
 files: [],
 premium: {type:Boolean, default: false}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the for loop and use **[`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/)** with the **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push)** operator to append multiple values to the array filed as follows:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id,
    { '$push': {
        'files': {
            '$each': files.map(f => ({ name: f.filename }))
        }
    } },
    (err, doc) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(doc);
    }
);
```

You may want to update your schema to explicitly define the files array field:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true, lowercase:true, unique: true},
   hash: {type: String, required: true },
   files: [{ name: String }],
   premium: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for me as the console.log(doc) outputs:
 { premium: false,
 _id: xxxxxxxx,
 name: xxx,
 hash: xxxxxxxxxxxxx,
 files: [],
 __v: 0 }

Comment: @StephenToth What’s the contents of the files array i.e console.log(files)?

Comment: [ { fieldname: 'upload', originalname: '1533734295.png', encoding: '7bit', mimetype: 'image/png', destination: './uploads', filename: '90f0a33c739465bd.png', path: 'uploads/90f0a33c739465bd.png', size: 70933 } ]

Comment: Sorry to waste your time, its working as soon as i removed the {name:String} from the schema